# Define overlap at external API

Tags: c++

I am using two external API in my project. At some point I use:

```
xstring msg = pfcex->GetMessage();
```

GetMessage is defined at some header file at API#1.

At External API#2 (Winsock.h) I have:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetMessage  GetMessageW
#else
#define GetMessage  GetMessageA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

API#2 is breaking #1. GetMessage is being replaced by GetMessageW.
How can I prevent the define to be applied there?

Comment: `#undef` it after `#include <winsock.h>`.

Comment: Maybe something like `#ifdef GetMessageW #undef GetMessageW #endif` will help?

Comment: I tried to `#undef` at multiple places. I can't figure this out.

Comment: I created a better self library, and know at my main file, I have:`#include <api1.h>
#include <api2.h>
#undef GetMessage`. This works fine